# Substituir NA pelo valor mínimo em um conjunto de dados

Tags: r, tidyverse

Gostaria de construir uma função para substituir os valores `NA` em meu conjunto de dados pelo valor mínimo da população para cada espécie de um conjunto de dados.

```r
df <- 
  structure(list(site = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S1", "S2", "S3", 
    "S4"), sp = c("sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp2", "sp2", "sp2", 
    "sp2"), populacao = c(NA, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df
  site  sp populacao
1   S1 sp1        NA
2   S2 sp1         2
3   S3 sp1         5
4   S4 sp1         1
5   S1 sp2         1
6   S2 sp2         5
7   S3 sp2        NA
8   S4 sp2        NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recomendo usar funções dos pacotes presentes no `tidyverse`, em particular a função `replace_na` do pacote `tidyr`. Essa função permite que valores `NA` sejam substituídos a critério do usuário. O código a seguir faz o que é pedido:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  structure(list(site = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S1", "S2", "S3", 
    "S4"), sp = c("sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp1", "sp2", "sp2", "sp2", 
    "sp2"), populacao = c(NA, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df
#>   site  sp populacao
#> 1   S1 sp1        NA
#> 2   S2 sp1         2
#> 3   S3 sp1         5
#> 4   S4 sp1         1
#> 5   S1 sp2         1
#> 6   S2 sp2         5
#> 7   S3 sp2        NA
#> 8   S4 sp2        NA

df |> 
  group_by(sp) |> 
  mutate(populacao = replace_na(populacao, min(populacao, na.rm = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#> # Groups:   sp [2]
#>   site  sp    populacao
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 S1    sp1           1
#> 2 S2    sp1           2
#> 3 S3    sp1           5
#> 4 S4    sp1           1
#> 5 S1    sp2           1
#> 6 S2    sp2           5
#> 7 S3    sp2           1
#> 8 S4    sp2           1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Em detalhes, o que o código está fazendo a cada linha é

- pegando o conteúdo do conjunto de dados `df` e passando para a linha seguinte
- agrupando os dados por espécie (`sp`, no caso do problema)
- substituindo os `NA` com a função `replace_na`: para isso, é procurado o mínimo (`min`) de `população` para cada nível de `sp`, pois os dados foram agrupados por espécie na linha anterior

Na última linha de código, note o uso do argumento `na.rm = TRUE` para que este mínimo seja de fato encontrado, ignorando os `NA` dessa variável. Se isso não fosse feito, o mínimo não seria encontrado, retornando `NA` como resposta.

Comment: obigado Marcus Nunes.

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta está com a *tag* tidyverse, mas para ficar registrado, algumas alternativas com outros pacotes.

### data.table

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, populacao := fifelse(is.na(populacao), min(populacao, na.rm = TRUE), populacao), sp]

dt
#>    site  sp populacao
#> 1:   S1 sp1         1
#> 2:   S2 sp1         2
#> 3:   S3 sp1         5
#> 4:   S4 sp1         1
#> 5:   S1 sp2         1
#> 6:   S2 sp2         5
#> 7:   S3 sp2         1
#> 8:   S4 sp2         1
```

### zoo

```
library(zoo)

df$populacao <- with(df, na.aggregate(populacao, sp, FUN = min))

df
#>   site  sp populacao
#> 1   S1 sp1         1
#> 2   S2 sp1         2
#> 3   S3 sp1         5
#> 4   S4 sp1         1
#> 5   S1 sp2         1
#> 6   S2 sp2         5
#> 7   S3 sp2         1
#> 8   S4 sp2         1
```